# How to convert a Haskell Traversable into a Vector?

Tags: haskell, vector, traversable

If I have a [`Traversable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Traversable.html) instance, `xs`, how do I convert it into a [`Vector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector)?

Answer (score 11):

All `Traversable` instances are also `Foldable`, so you can write something like

```
toVector :: Foldable t => t a -> Vector a
toVector = Vector.fromList . Foldable.toList
{-# INLINE toVector #-}
```

This might make an intermediate list though, if that doesn't get fused away. The inlining should help make fusion more likely.

Comment: I just had a shot and it seems like the larger obstacle is that the `Vector` consumers, fundamentally, can only fuse with data types that can be efficiently turned into the library's `Stream` type. So I don't think you can fuse `Vector` consumers with an arbitrary `Foldable`s for reasons similar to why you can't implement `uncons :: [a] -> Maybe (a, [a])` efficiently with just `foldr`. (Try writing `toVector` in terms of `Foldable.foldr` and `Stream.unfoldr`, without effectively reimplementing `Foldable.toList`—I don't think it can be done...) So your solution may well be optimal.